# Pass indexPath.row to button in a custom cell using SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a simple table view, with a custom cell build in it, the custom cell has two buttons ( later they will be used as Down Vote and UpVote buttons ), is there a way for to pass the indexPath.row value to the button, in order to me to identify which cell button was clicked?

**TablewViewController.swift**

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

        cell.piadaTitulo.text = "Lorem Ipsum"
        cell.piadaDescription.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo volutpat lectus, vitae semper tortor finibus at. Cras erat ligula, egestas sed tincidunt eget, condimentum maximus lectus. Aenean varius semper tellus, id congue lacus pretium a"


        return cell
    }
```

**CustomTableViewCell.Swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var piadaTitulo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var piadaDescription: UILabel!

@IBAction func piadaUpVote(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("UPVOTE clicked")
}

@IBAction func piadaDownVote(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("DOWNVOTE clicked")
}
```

[image: Simple Table View]

Comment: you could assign the `tag` property to the row in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. Then just use sender.tag in the `IBAction`s to know the row.

Comment: i should add the tag to the cell? like cell.tag = indexPath.row?

Answer (score 3):

Screw tags. Use this extension for an easy find of the indexPath of the button's cell.

```
// MARK: - UITableView
extension UITableView {
    func indexPathForView (view : UIView) -> NSIndexPath? {
        let location = view.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:self)
        return indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)
    }
}

@IBAction func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    // For a button press
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForView(button)!

    // Do thangs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could get the superview of the button which is the cell itself, and you dont need the indexpath

```
sender.superview
```

Regards

Comment: Not in every case. contentView, subviews?